# Haskell - How to show nothing as result in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

Im getting started to Haskell, and im trying to define the factorial function that takes one number and, if the number is negative, show nothing as result. Like this (just an example):

```
    *Main> factorial 8
    40320
    *Main> factorial (-1)
    *Main>
```

Is it possible, and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? It's just GHCi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it pure then you can do it by defining a new result type and defining `show` to convert to an empty string if the result is invalid:

```
data FactResult = R Integer | Invalid

instance Show FactResult where
    show (R i) = show i
    show Invalid = ""

factorial n | n < 0 = Invalid
factorial n = R $ product [1..n]
```

Comment: That doesn't *quite* do what the question asks for: there will be an extra blank line in GHCi.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this with just a function, and it's probably not what you want anyhow. A function *always* has to return *something*, even if it's just a dummy value that represents not having a valid result! This is useful because it means the result of your function can always be used by other parts of your program—everything is more composable.

The usual idiomatic solution is to use the `Maybe` type, which lets you return either `Just` the result or `Nothing`:

```
factorial n | n < 0     = Nothing
            | n < 2     = Just 1
            | otherwise = ...
```

If you *really* want your behavior in GHCi, you can print out the result you want instead of returning it directly. This gives you more control over how the output looks, but it means you won't be able to reuse the result of your function directly. You can do it like this:

```
factorialPrint n | n < 0     = return () -- an IO action that does nothing
                 | otherwise = print (factorial n)
```

Instead of producing a result, this function produces an **IO action**. GHCi then executes this action and doesn't print anything itself, which means you have to print the result yourself explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way to do something like this would be to use Maybe.

```
factorial n
    | n < 0     = Nothing
    | n == 1    = Just 1
    | otherwise = fmap (*n) $ factorial (n-1)
```

This outputs "Just n!" with an input of anything >= 0 and "Nothing" otherwise.

If you really want a blank response.

```
maybeStr Nothing  = ""
maybeStr (Just x) = show x
```

Then to run print it you would say:

```
f = putStrLn . maybeStr . factorial
f 4 -- would print 24
f (-1) -- would print blank line
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but we have to slightly change the factorial function:

```
fac :: Int -> IO ()
fac n
  | n < 0 = return ()
  | otherwise = print $ facHelp n
    where
      facHelp n = <your factorial function>
```

Now, in addition to the standard factorial, we check the input first and if the input is smaller than 0, we just return a thing called unit, which is nothing (to see at least). If the input is valid for the factorial, we will just print it normally.